# setdiff two single column data frames

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, intersection

I'm having a problem with a very simple issue and I don't know how to sort it out. Here's the deal. I have two one column data frames

```
a <- data.frame(C=c("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8"))
b <- data.frame(C=c("c1","c4","c5","c8"))
```

I would like to get one column dataframe with the entries that do NOT appear in b but they are in a. ie. a dataframe with "c2","c3","c6","c7".
I tried

```
c <- setdiff(a,b)
```

but I got the a dataframe and also with

```
c <- merge(a,b,all.x=TRUE)
```

I don't get what I want it. so do you know where I am wrong?

Comment: Isn't it `setdiff(a$C, b$C)`?

Comment: I must be honest. I dind't think about that... the only thing here is I don't get a data frame

Comment: you're right! :) and @akrun gave a compact solution herebelow. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(a,b)
```

Or

```
data.frame(C= setdiff(a[,1], b[,1]))
```

Comment: thanks! but is it really not possible with the base libraries?

Comment: @Stefano  You can use `setdiff` on the first columns